# Logback thread was blocked with virtual thread envrionment

Tags: logback, project-loom, virtual-threads, openjdk-21

The detail problem can also see in the github issue: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/issues/767

I don't know how to solve this problem and i look for your suggestions. Thanks first.

I have dump the thread stack.
And found it was blocked in the logback method and with LockSupport.park.
But i don't know what make the problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Could you run `jcmd <pid> Thread.dump_to_file <filename>` command when this happens and post it there? I see from your `stack1.txt` that you are using virtual threads, but traditional thread dump does not favor virtual threads.

Comment: I have dump by the jcmd command. and post in the github issue.

Comment: What java version exactly are you using and on what operating system? Could you run `java --version` and post it there? From the dump with virtual threads you posted it follows that you have 9228 virtual threads parked while waiting for 2 logback resource, but from the line numbers they wait on I suspect there is a _pinning_. Could you diagnose the pinning (-Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full, details are at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html)  and post relevant data there?

Comment: java -version Info:
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21+35-2513)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-2513, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: I have tried -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full in the jvm argument. But the springboot program start failed. And i have not fix the problem which you can see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77779953/spring-boot-virtual-threads-djdk-tracepinnedthreads-full-causes-tasks-to-hang

Comment: This is not how this site is supposed to be used. Post your problem description and all relevant information *here*, in your question. Not on an external site and not in comments.

Comment: @igor.zh i have open the tracePinnedThreads argument and the stack trace. But is seems the argument has some problem too. You can see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39233 .  I need more time to find the logback hang  problem.

Comment: As for tracing of pinning, Alan Bateman recommends JFR (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/17221) instead of `-Djdk.tracePinnedThreads`. In respect of your initial logback problem, which, to my understanding, may or may not be related to v-threads pinning, could you come with an MFR (Minimal Reproducible Example) (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It is quite difficult to analyze dumps with tens of thousands threads.

Comment: @Holger, I agree that Java version and MFR (if available) should be placed into the question instead of the comments. But what if an OP is unable to come with the MFR? Should this kind of issues be left out of SO scope?

Comment: @igor.zh I don’t know what you mean with MFR and I didn’t ask for it. Just for the very information that is now spread over GitHub and the comment section, to be included in the question.