# Java Virtual Threads causes application to hang on ReentrantLocks in logback

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, virtual-threads

I am experiencing a problem after migration from java 17 to java 21 with Spring Boot 3.2.1 and Tomcat 10. Virtual threads are enabled and used (e.g. I can see that tomcat spawns new virtual threads while handling requests, spring scheduled tasks are executed within virtual threads).

Problem occurs completely randomly. At some point application stop to respond to any HTTP requests including healthcheck on spring actuator. I did thread dump using jcmd and what I notice is that some threads are stuck on logback Reentrant locks. This includes virtual and non-virtual threads. Here are some examples:

```
#124 "org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#4-1-C-1"
      java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:221)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:754)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:990)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:153)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:322)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeBytes(OutputStreamAppender.java:200)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeOut(OutputStreamAppender.java:193)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:237)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:102)
      ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:85)
      ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:272)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:259)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:426)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:386)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:780)
      org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.writeLog(LogContext.java:434)
      org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.info(LogContext.java:382)
```

```
#229434 "scheduling-4181" virtual
      java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.park(VirtualThread.java:582)
      java.base/java.lang.System$2.parkVirtualThread(System.java:2639)
      java.base/jdk.internal.misc.VirtualThreads.park(VirtualThreads.java:54)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:219)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:754)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:990)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:153)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:322)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeBytes(OutputStreamAppender.java:200)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.writeOut(OutputStreamAppender.java:193)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.subAppend(OutputStreamAppender.java:237)
      ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender.append(OutputStreamAppender.java:102)
      ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:85)
        ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:272)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:259)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:426)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:386)
      ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:780)
      org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.writeLog(LogContext.java:434)
      org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LogContext$LocationAwareKafkaLogger.info(LogContext.java:382)
      org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(KafkaConsumer.java:912)
      org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.subscribe(KafkaConsumer.java:944)
```

There are Kafka consumers that starts together with Spring context and some that starts only during Spring scheduled task (these binds to virtual threads).

Moreover I can see a lot of tomcat virtual threads with completely empty stack frames, e.g.:
`#230463 "tomcat-handler-109939" virtual`

Threads that were supposed to carry virtual threads are not 100% utilized, I can see that some of them are really carrying virtual threads:

```
#241 "ForkJoinPool-3-worker-4"
      java.base/jdk.internal.vm.Continuation.run(Continuation.java:251)
      java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.runContinuation(VirtualThread.java:221)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1423)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:387)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1312)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1843)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1808)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)
```

while some are idle:

```
#249 "ForkJoinPool-3-worker-5"
      java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:371)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1893)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1809)
      java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:188)
```

I can simply disable virtual threads support for Spring, but I would like to understand the problem. Is it some kind of deadlock? How to track it?

Comment: are you also running with [-Djdk.tracePinnedThreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77779953/spring-boot-virtual-threads-djdk-tracepinnedthreads-full-causes-tasks-to-hang) set?

Comment: further follow up resources relating to it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/39233 and https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/17221

Comment: +1 for using correct word - _hang_. If it does not happen when virtual threads turned off, then this is indeed _hanging_, not a _classic_ deadlock. Also be aware than you could run your Kafka Consumers or whatever on virtual threads selectively.

Comment: @Naman -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads option is not enabled.

Comment: I would more suspect this bug: https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1711